# Is there inverse to right for this function?

Tags: functions, inverse, inverse-function

We have function $g: \mathbb R\to[11/4, \infty)$, with $g(x)=x^2-3x+5$ and we have to check if there exists $h:\mathbb R \to(-1, \infty) $ with property $g \circ h=1_{[11/4, \infty)}$, where $\circ$ means the composition of $g$ and $h$, and if it exists the problem ask to determine it.

I want to say that if $g$ is not a surjective function, that there not exist a inverse to right, but I don't know if it is totally correct, and from there how to find $h$?

Comment: What do ypu mean by $g \circ h=1_{[11/4, \infty)}$?

Comment: @gimusi  This means that h is an inverse of g and 1_{[11/4, \infty)} means identity function. $1_{A}(x) = x$ for each x in A. Or it if neutral element in a group of functions.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

$g$ is surjective because.

$g(x)=x^2-3x+5=\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)^2+\frac{11}{4}$. So the range of $g$ is $\left[\frac{11}{4},\infty\right)$.

Since $g$ is surjective so $g$ does have a right inverse. To find that
\begin{align*}
y & = x^2-3x+5\\
x^2-3x+(5-y)&=0\\
x & = \frac{3\pm\sqrt{9-4(5-y)}}{2}\\
x & = \frac{3\pm\sqrt{4y-11}}{2}.
\end{align*}
Now you have to choose the correct branch for the right inverse $h$. Can you proceed from here?

Also you need to define your $h$ separately for $\Bbb{R}-\left[\frac{11}{4},\infty\right)$.

Comment: Yes, I can sole it now but I have two question if you can answer: Why define h for $\Bbb{R}-\left[\frac{11}{4},\infty\right)$? And second: if g was not a surjective function, we could draw the conclusion that he don't have a inverse to right ? Thanks!

Comment: @Raul1998 the reason you have to define $h$ on that set is because the function we will get for $h$ from the expression I have in my answer gives you $h$ for only $x \geq 11/4$. But the requirement you have in your question about the domain of $h$ is that it should be ALL real numbers.  Regarding your second question, the answer is yes. If $g$ was not onto, then the right inverse wouldn't exist.

Comment: You meant to write $g(x) = x^2 - 3x  + 5 = \left(x - \frac{3}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{11}{4}$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks for pointing out the typo.